# How can i load an array of images in html5 canvas and swap one of the images on button click

Tags: javascript, html, canvas

i'm trying to build a bike configurator. This is my problem.

How can i load and array of images to construct the bike and another array with parts on the right from which when the user click i take the part and load it on the left where is the bike without preloading the entire canvas again. the new image will be the same width and height and should be on the same x/y position. This is how i load and array of images, but then i don't know how to swap them. I know that i can't clear the image that is loaded on the canvas and i have to draw the new one on top but i don't know how.

```
<script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8">
function loadImages(sources, callback){
    var images = {};
    var loadedImages = 0;
    var numImages = 0;
    // get num of sources
    for (var src in sources) {
      numImages++;
    }
    for (var src in sources) {
      images[src] = new Image();
      images[src].onload = function(){
        if (++loadedImages >= numImages) {
          callback(images);
        }
      };
      images[src].src = sources[src];
    }
  }

window.onload = function(images){
  var canvas = document.getElementById("config");
  var context = canvas.getContext("2d");

  var sources = {
      one: "one.jpg",
      two: "two.jpg"
  };

  loadImages(sources, function(images){
      context.drawImage(images.one, 100, 100, 180, 200);
      context.drawImage(images.two, 280, 100, 180, 200);
      });
};
</script>
```

How can i change image two.jpg on button click. The button should be outside the canvas.

Comment: Have you looked into [fabric.js](http://kangax.github.com/fabric.js/)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
button.addEventListener('click', function () {
  canvas.width = canvas.width; // redraws canvas
  sources.two = 'three.jpg';

  // fyi, you are drawing the images as many times as there are sources.
  loadImages(sources, function(images){
      context.drawImage(images.one, 100, 100, 180, 200);
      context.drawImage(images.two, 280, 100, 180, 200);
   });
}, false);
```